# Behavior of the mouse wheel changed in Windows 10 1903 in respect to scrolling focused or hovered controls

Tags: windows, windows-10, accessibility, windows-10-v1903

[image: scroll options]

With a recent windows 10 update I am given only two options:

1. scroll (with the mouse wheel) the focused window/control
2. scroll (with the mouse wheel) the hovered window/control

In the past it used to do both with **focus having the precedence on hover**:

- If am focusing a scrollable window/control then it would scroll that one
- Otherwise it would fallback to scrolling the hovered window/control

This change has completely messed up my workflow in adobe software which I used for decades.

Also I checked, it's not a problem of Adobe, it does that everywhere in Windows (even the start menu, I am forced to click the popup first before I can scroll it! LOL!)

Is there a way to revert to the old behavior?

Comment: It also behaves like that in 1809 fwiw

Comment: I am not sure if I skipped that version. I usually do updates. But the change is relatively recent for me.

Comment: Tech note: Take a careful look and use correct tags, please. Question re-tagged from [windows-10-1903](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-1903) to [windows-10-v1903](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1903).